# Find the span of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

Find the span of $U=\{2,\cos x,\sin x:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ ($U$ is the subset of a space of real functions)  and $V=\{(a,b,b,...,b),(b,a,b,...,b),...,(b,b,b,...,a): a,b\in \mathbb{R},V\subset \mathbb{R^n},n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Attempt:

Objects in $U$ :$2,\cos x,\sin x$ are linearly independent, so they span $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Let ,$n=3\Rightarrow [V]=        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & b \\
        b & a & b \\
        b & b & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

$rref[V]=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow $ vectors in $V$ span $\mathbb{R^3}$, if $a,b\neq 0$.

But because $V\subset\mathbb{R^n}\Rightarrow $ vectors span $\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The objects $2, \cos(\cdot), \sin(\cdot)$ are functions defined on the real line - how can they span $\mathbb R^3$, which are not functions, but only column vectors? Your approach for the second question is a) not general enough (don't pick an $n$ you like!) and b) not correct since vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ are column vectors with $n$ rows, and vectors in $\mathbb R^(n-1)$ are column vectors with $n-1$ rows.

Comment: @Roland, Could you explain the method for finding the span of $U$ and $V$? I am a little confused because objects in $U$ are not vectors. Also, if $V\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ it's elements can't span $\mathbb{R^n}$.